# How do i use Ninject 2 in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

Ive searched everywhere, i can't seem to find a way to implement ninject in my project. Ive heard of deriving MvcApplication to the NinjectHttpApplication. But NinjectHttpApplication isnt found even if i add the lib to the reference. I can't find Ninject.Web.Mvc. Does anyone have a guide somewhere in order to make this work, all i want to do is be able to bind my interface from my domain to existing implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/30/dependency-injection-in-nerddinner-app-using-ninject.aspx

Looks like the bulk of it is done via

```
Global.asax.cs
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
```

Replace `Application_Start` with

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MobileCapableWebFormViewEngine());
    RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

Then create your Ninject modules and configure the kernel, all is explained in the blog post and source code is available here: http://nerddinneraddons.codeplex.com/

While the above is for MVC 2, it should still apply

Comment: Can't build the librairies. (i use build-release) i get :     [exec] fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

     [exec] External Program Failed: C:\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3/../tools/git/git.ex
e (return code was 128)
"BUILD FAILED"

Comment: You can't build what libraries? Ninject? or the nerd dinner application?

Comment: Did you install it with nuget?

Comment: Nope, should i ? also on a side note it seem in MVC i can make it work in the ApplicationStart via a controller factory i am right ? there no need to use NinjectHttpApplication i believe. Can you confirm ?

Comment: I can't confirm, but I would suggest using Nuget and following the guide above, nuget is supposed to ease the pain with these sort of things

Answer (score 3):

See my blog post about the MVC3 extension here: http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/

The source code at github comes with a full featured sample application: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

The binaries can be found either at github: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/archives/master
Or on the build server: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/project.html?projectId=project3&tab=projectOverview

Comment: I never seen a ninject.web.mvc.. only a system.web.mvc. Where is ninject.web.mvc ?