# Ninject with ASP.NET MVC 3 global.asax rewrite

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

In my ASP.NET MVC v2 app's global.asax.cs I have the Ninject v2 wireup. I was looking for complete information on how to do the same in MVC 3, the right way using `IDependencyResolver` but could only find many references to the fact that one should use this interface but not the actual code how to use it.
For instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783372/ninject-with-mvc3-rtm) it only says we should use it. I've checked the [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) but it lacks detailed info.

I've downloaded the Ninject.web.mvc for MVC3 and the latest Ninject 2.1 with web support and added both to my solution. That's what I have now. I've referred to this [piece of code](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/mvc3ninject.zip) by ScottGu but it is designed around the class `MvcServiceLocator`, which does not exist anymore. All in all I was unable to find an example of how to do it with the RTMs versions of both MVC 3 and the new Ninject for MVC3.

Now do I need to inherit my HTTP application from NinjectHttpApplication like in version 2 or what?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783372/ninject-with-mvc3-rtm/4784995#4784995 ? 

There's a nuget package, an article and ninject.extensions.web now supports MVC 3. There are about 10 copies of this question, can this be removed please?

Comment: Not one of the questions already one the site has a complete and clear solution. This is a growing problem with SO. Multiple questions with common topic and many times without a single useful response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC3 + Ninject - How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358395/mvc3-ninject-how-to)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777332/how-do-i-use-ninject-2-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-application

Comment: I voted close, so it's fine with me.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searches on the web I found probably the most complete and up-to-date solution which is described [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/) by Remo Gloor.

Comment: I think you didnt look properly http://www.google.ie/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Remo: is kinda part of the problem - he's answered the "how do I use ninject with MVC 3" question 3 times. The first one I cited was prob before he wrote the article. @Remo et al, instead of another copy/paste of the answer to this question, we need votes to close on these questions and/or a comment link to a previous answer and then let questioners remove it

Comment: @Ruben: I agree. Unfortunately, I can't cast any close votes yet.

Comment: @Remo: We'll get you the upvotes and get you out of this unsung hero badge rut! (I sub'd to your SO rss feed hence awareness of the number of MVC3 answers and the duplication of the questions)